# Fetch specific input value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can I retrieve the value of my searchfield when I press post?

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?page=search" id="FrontSearchForm">
    <input type="text" name="searchstring" id="searchstring" placeholder="Search" />
</form>
```

The searchstring should be fetched in this jQuery file:

```js
(function($) {
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
var searchstring = $('#searchstring').val();
var mipage = getUrlVars()["id"];

$AjaxPHP = "SearchAjax.php";

 $.fn.scrollPagination = function(options) {
  
  var settings = { 
   nop     : 16, // The number of posts per scroll to be loaded
   offset  : 0, // Initial offset, begins at 0 in this case
   error   : 'Ikke mere indhold!', // When the user reaches the end this is the message that is
                               // displayed. You can change this if you want.
   delay   : 500, // When you scroll down the posts will load after a delayed amount of time.
                  // This is mainly for usability concerns. You can alter this as you see fit
   scroll  : true // The main bit, if set to false posts will not load as the user scrolls. 
                  // but will still load if the user clicks.
  }
  
  // Extend the options so they work with the plugin
  if(options) {
   $.extend(settings, options);
  }
  
  // For each so that we keep chainability.
  return this.each(function() {  
   
   // Some variables 
   $this = $(this);
   $settings = settings;
   var offset = $settings.offset;
   var busy = false; // Checks if the scroll action is happening 
                     // so we don't run it multiple times
   
   // Custom messages based on settings
   if($settings.scroll == true) $initmessage = '<div class="ScrollLoader"><p>Scroll for at se mere indhold</p></div>';
   else $initmessage = '<div class="ScrollLoader"><p>Klik for at se mere indhold</p></div>';
   
   // Append custom messages and extra UI
   $this.append('<div class="content"></div><div class="loading-bar">'+$initmessage+'</div>');

   function getData() {
    
    // Post data to ajax.php
    $.post($AjaxPHP, {
     action        : 'scrollpagination',
        number        : $settings.nop,
        offset        : offset,
     mipage      : mipage,
     searchstring  : searchstring,
         
    }, function(data) {
      
     // Change loading bar content (it may have been altered)
     $this.find('.loading-bar').html($initmessage);
      
     // If there is no data returned, there are no more posts to be shown. Show error
     if(data == "") { 
      $this.find('.loading-bar').html($settings.error); 
     }
     else {
      
      // Offset increases
         offset = offset+$settings.nop; 
          
      // Append the data to the content div
         $this.find('.content').append(data);
      
      // No longer busy! 
      busy = false;
     } 
      
    });
     
   } 
   
   getData(); // Run function initially
   
   // If scrolling is enabled
   if($settings.scroll == true) {
    // .. and the user is scrolling
    $(window).scroll(function() {
     
     // Check the user is at the bottom of the element
     if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $this.height() && !busy) {
      
      // Now we are working, so busy is true
      busy = true;
      
      // Tell the user we're loading posts
      $this.find('.loading-bar').html('<div class="ScrollLoader"><p><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> Henter indhold...</p></div>');
      
      // Run the function to fetch the data inside a delay
      // This is useful if you have content in a footer you
      // want the user to see.
      setTimeout(function() {
       
       getData();
       
      }, $settings.delay);
       
     } 
    });
   }
   
   // Also content can be loaded by clicking the loading bar/
   $this.find('.loading-bar').click(function() {
   
    if(busy == false) {
     busy = true;
     getData();
    }
   
   });
   
  });
 }
 
})(jQuery);
```

Well.. As you can see, this jQuery file communicates with SearchAjax.php, where I am fetching the results from the database.

The problem I think, is `var searchstring = $('#searchstring').val();`

Comment: alert value of searchstring or `console.log(searchstring );` and check console for its value and also check what is posted in ajax request in console

Comment: add value="" in your input `alert(searchstring);` and see what is bee alerted

Comment: Try using double quotes:

    var searchstring = $("#searchstring").val();

Comment: @liquidflo - That didn't work.

Comment: @soul,@yiiframe - it alerts undefined - wierd.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soul2sunny/dbgncjpz/ check that link it works for me

Comment: @soul - Yes, it works. Hmm Maybe it's because I'm showing my php-results in a div via jQuery.

Comment: @soul - I have index.php where the form is. Then when you press the search button, the form redirects you to "search.php" where there is a div, where the jquery is called - can that have something to do with it?

Comment: but your jquery needs to fetch the input value but it is not able to fetch it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you submit the form back to the server, the value of the input will be available in your `index.php` code. If you don't include this value in your output, then the value will not be available to your client side javascript

One way to do this is to have `search.php` include a hidden input that has a the searchvalue passed to it from `index.php`

```
<input type="hidden" id="searchstring" value="valueFromIndex.php" />
```